# Ajax load data to several places at once

Tags: ajax, load

I would like to load a page and then fill in some placeholders on it with data via Ajax request. I did that with jquery, but the problem is this: the file that I fetch with Ajax is time-consuming, and I was able to load data only to one placeholder at a time: `$("#div1").load("info.php");`.

I would like to send data for all placeholders in one response but can't get the idea **how can I put it into all placeholders at once**.

Please advice if this is possible.

I'd really like to load array of values via Ajax then put it into placeholders (divs) with some `for` in JS, but can't find a way to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the data from one request then try one ajax call and iterate like so...

```
array = {'id': {'pointer': 'div_id', 'content': 'the content'}}

//in a for loop  -> item
$(item['pointer']).html(item['content'])
```